# Read single line pickle python

Tags: python, pickle, readline

im doing some simulations with python and save the results using pickle.dump(). Now i have an enormous amount of data wich i need to read. The data consist of matrices (a lot of lines of numbers) each saved in a single file. I need to be able to read the information efficiently.

- How can i read a single line of the matrix withot uploading the complete file?
- How can i read a specific set of lines (say from the line 1000 to the 2000) whithout uploading the complete file?
  Here is the code i used to save the data:

  ```
  for j in range(61):
      for l in range(31):
          X = zeros([100000,100])
          K = k[j]
          A = a[l]
          X = RK4(deriv,dt,pasos,xo,n,w,b,K,g,A,V)
          pickle.dump( X, open( 'Vrc'+'dk_'+ str(K) + 'alpha_' + str(A) , "wb" ) )
  ```

Comment: As you save the matrix with `pickle` it creates a big blob of data that cannot be read line by line, it doesn't mean anything if it is not complete. You have to use another saving format.

Answer (score -2):

Try using generators when doing pickle.load(): `yield pickle.load(...)`

Also have a look at [cPickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle).